# Is there a way to mark violations as `False Positive` in bulk?

Tags: sonarqube, sonata-admin, sonarqube-scan

Is there a way to mark violations as `False Positive` in bulk in SonarQube?
I know the older versions have switch off violations plugin through which it is achieved. Please let me know how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oldest supported version SonarQube version is 7.9.3. This version provides a feature to do it OOTB. Steps:

1. open project
2. click `Issues` tab
3. check checkbox next to the `Bulk Change` button
4. uncheck issues which you don't want to mark as `False Positive`
5. click the `Bulk Change` button
6. in popup go to `Transition` and click `Resolve as false positive`
7. click the `Apply` button

You can also add comment and/or send email notification for every change.

[image: steps to mark issues as false positive in bulk]